# SharePoint 2010 - customize a reusable workflow

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

Good morning. I am using SharePoint 2013 but created a SharePoint 2010 Reusable Workflow in SharePoint Designer. It is an Approval workflow that I want to use on 5 different Meet-Me line request lists. The workflow is the same for all except that the approval email that goes to the requester has the different meet-me line info (access codes, etc).  Is there a way to customize the reusable workflow for each line?  Thank you.

Scott

Answer (score 0):

Its a good question but I don't think Microsoft provided any option to customize the reusable work flow.

I also tried before but no luck.